# how do you do a fresh install of ubuntu 14.4 on an existing ubuntu partition

Tags: boot

i can only open ubuntu in safe mode now after mistakenly upgrading to ubuntu 14.4 lts,having already done it about a month before. i responded to a pop up window without thinking. How do i do a fresh install? when i select the ubuntu option on boot up now, the the computer freezes and the cursor disapears. thence my using safe mode.
thank you.

Comment: try sh cdromupgrade with previous versions..i use alternative cd to install ubuntu and here always come partition manager..

Answer (score 0):

First of all do a backup of your existing files in a different disk altogether or at least in a different partition, Focus on what's in your home folder.

Then create a liveDVD or liveUSB.

Boot from the medium just created and choose the install Ubuntu option. If the installer offers the "Upgrade Ubuntu" option then choose that. If not, choose the "something else" option. When gparted opens, choose your current Ubuntu partition as root partition and mark for formatting and continue with the installation.

Copy your home folder files back and reinstall the software you need.